# .remove() method returns None when it should return a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, methods, return

I'll let the code speak for itself, as I've been heaving a headache over this for a while now. 
Below is a test I've put together to simplify the investigation.

```
# This is a python file containing a dictionary of tuples with RGB colours (R, G, B)

import random


colours = {
    'black': (0, 0, 0,),
    'white': (255, 255, 255,),

    'red': (255, 0, 0,),
    'green': (0, 255, 0,),
    'blue': (0, 0, 255,),

    'yellow': (255, 255, 0,),
    'purple': (255, 0, 255,),
    'brown': (139, 69, 19,),
    'orange': (255, 165, 0,),
    'cyan': (0, 255, 255,),
}

print('1', colours)
print('2', list(colours))
print('3', ((list(colours)).remove('black')))
print('4', random.choice((list(colours)).remove('black')))
print('5', colours[random.choice((list(colours)).remove('black'))])
```

These test print statements print respectively:

> **1** {'black': (0, 0, 0), 'white': (255, 255, 255), 'red': (255, 0, 0), 'green': (0, 255, 0), 'blue': (0, 0, 255), 'yellow': (255, 255,
>   0), 'purple': (255, 0, 255), 'brown': (139, 69, 19), 'orange': (255,
>   165, 0), 'cyan': (0, 255, 255)}
>
> **2** ['black', 'white', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'purple', 'brown', 'orange', 'cyan']
>
> **3** None
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/macja/PycharmProjects/pygame_sentdex_tutorial/colours.py",
>   line 21, in 
>       print('4', random.choice((list(colours)).remove('black')))   File "C:\Users\macja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\random.py",
>   line 259, in choice
>       i = self._randbelow(len(seq)) TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

So as you can see, it all seems to come down at .remove('black')
I'm not particularly interested in a workaround, that's easy. I'd like to understand what happened to cause this problem, as I'm just learning python.

Comment: No, `remove` - like `append` - always returns None.

Comment: Why do you think `.remove` should return a list?

Comment: `remove` operates in-place.

Comment: See @DanielRoseman; The following errors are occuring, too, because you have removed `black`! You cannot remove something that DNE.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I understand now. I was wrongly under the impression that .remove() returns a list.

Comment: This iteration of the question is a powerful cautionary tale. Rather than "having a headache" over code that lasts "for a while", make sure to check your assumptions and read documentation.